# Local STS to production

Tags: wif, claims-based-identity, claims

I am now working on a web project where the authentication mechanism chosen is windows authentication(intranet application). Once the project goes live, after a gap of two months or so, an STS will be set up. Then the web project should start using it with out much change to the code. How to do it?

I plan to use claims based authentication using WIF 4.5 with my own STS ( a WCF project/web application) and take it to live. once the STS is setup in intranet(ADFS)/cloud(WAAD). I simply change the local STS URL to new 'original' STS.

1) Will it work?
2) Can the local STS be a dll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

STS is not required for Windows authentication, with .NET 4.5 Claims are included in framework, in fact no extra setup/configuration is required to support Claims. Moreover STS is required only if you are trying to federate.

See [How-To](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh987035%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

It is not a good idea to deploy a custom developed STS to production environment, you should be using ADFS or Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2 or any other similar product for federation.

Comment: That was the scenario I was looking for . Implement claims based authentication in code with out much additional work(external). And when ADFS/STS is setup use it with minimum change(eg: Just config change). I have a question though , the WIF pipeline won't be set in claims based windows authentication case. It comes only when a STS is configured. Am I correct?

Comment: WindowsPrincipal & WindowsIdentity are derived from ClaimsPrincipal & ClaimsIdentity and Claims are included by default in Windows Authentication. Yes, you are required to make configuration changes only when you are using STS.

Comment: Also one more question. Later when ADFS(STS) comes in I need to deal with SAML tokens. How much of code would I be able to reuse from my 'claims based windows authentication'?

Comment: There will be no code change required, you will need to add FederationMetadata XML and other configuration. See one here for ThinkTecture - http://dotnetcodr.com/2013/03/11/claims-based-authentication-in-net4-5-mvc4-with-c-external-authentication-with-ws-federation-part-2-testing-a-real-sts/

Answer (score 2):

You will want to start by configuring your application as a Claims-Aware Application.

- Right click on the web project and choose **Identity and Access**. You
  will need the
  [latest](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e21bf653-dfe1-4d81-b3d3-795cb104066e)
  identity tools to see this option in the context menu.
- Choose **Local Development STS** for the time being.

This will modify your `web.config` with the `identityConfiguration` section and a `wsFederation` node that has the Local Development STS url. You will no longer be using Windows Authentication instead you can configure the settings in under the Local Development STS tab in Identity and Access tools dialog. This gives the flexibility of defining different claims that emulate what your custom STS will do in the future.

Now your application authentication will resemble a production environment without a real STS.

Here are some resources

- [How To MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh291061%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- Several [code samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh545413%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: So the local STS can be taken to production server and run there?

Comment: Also can I use thinkecture identityServer for this (windows authentication)?

Comment: No you would not take the local STS to any production environment. It is just for development. The STS is started automatically when you run a solution configured to use it. I have not looked into thinkecture, but it seems likely they support windows authentication.

Comment: Okay so no local STS but I could take a custom STS(a web app developed by me) or thinkecture to production for the first couple of months till I get a real STS intalled by the client. Am I right?

Comment: Do we really need a STS? because I see that we could simply use WIF module instead of a STS. and when STS  is ready just change config. "Authentication will be handled by WIF provided module or a third party Identity Provider (STS)." taken from http://cprakash.com/2013/01/03/identity-in-net-4-5-aka-wif/

Comment: An STS would abstract the authentication logic into a separate site. There are WIF modules that can configure the application to use a particular method like Forms Authentication, Windows, etc. You use claims authentication if you want to just communicate with an STS that decides which method to based on the incoming request or other factors.