# WIF with out using STS

Tags: wif, claims-based-identity, claims

Is it possible to use claims based authentication for active directory users(intranet) in a web application with out using STS? WIF needs to be used.

"Authentication will be handled by WIF provided module or a third party Identity Provider (STS)." taken from cprakash.com/2013/01/03/identity-in-net-4-5-aka-wif

Which is that WIF provided module that replaces STS?

My scenario:
I plan to take my web application to production with this WIF module. And when the real STS is setup by client then I plan to use it with minimum changes to my web application as I already use WIF.

Comment: It is possible with out STS. This question was answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530119/local-sts-to-production/20626965#20626965